# Dynamically change text color based on a value retrived from database

Tags: css, laravel

[enter image description here][1]I am working with PHP/Laravel. I query my TaskType model to retrieve specific key & values. I then proceed to assign a color based on the retrieved value. For example, if the value is START, i assign this value 'colorStart', which is just a variable that retrieves the associated color of my 'START' value.

```
public function index()
    {
        $eventStartData = TaskType::all()->where('event', 'START');
        $eventStopData = TaskType::all()->where('event', 'STOP');
        $eventReportData = TaskType::all()->where('event', 'REPORT');
        $colorStart = TaskType::all()->where('colors', '#4f5705');
        $colorStop = TaskType::all()->where('colors', '#f43f1a');
        $colorReport = TaskType::all()->where('colors', '#8acae7');
        $color = '' ;
    
        if($eventStartData){
            $color = $colorStart ;            
        }
    
        if($eventStopData){
            $color = $colorStop ;
        }
    
        if($eventReportData){
            $color = $colorReport ;
               
        }
    
    }
```

this is table-display html :

```
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 210px;">
            <table class="table" id="">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Program Time</th>
                        <th>Event</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Actual_time</th>
                        <th>Display_Message</th>
                    </tr>
                <tbody >
                @foreach($welcome as $key => $data)
                    <tr>    
                    <td>{{$data->program_time}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data->event}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data->message}}</td> 
                    <td>{{$data->actual_time}}</td>               
                    <td>{{$data->display_message}}</td>                  
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
        <div>
```

I am stuck and curious to know how i can dynamically change my <td {{$data->event}} element based on the colors I have defined in my index function ?

I have embedded a link. Sorry I do not have enough points to share an image. But if you check it out. Event is highlighted in green. I would like each event instance to reflect the color associated to it .
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQEnU.png

Comment: Add a style attribute, with the color?

Comment: pass the color to the view along with the data ? return View('viewname',compact('data','color'));

Comment: @GertB, yes . With the colors I have, how can I add a style attribute to my <td>  element ?

Comment: `style="color: '{{ $color }}'"`

Comment: btw the index function always return $colorReport, because all the if is true

Comment: @ucup. I fail to understand. I am just a beginner . Please if you could, enlighten me more.

Comment: Model::where() will always return an array of object.

so all the if condition is true,  $color will always be $colorReport

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what inside the $data->event is but i assume you want to dynamically change the column based on that value

first on your function is gonna be static because you want to call it from everywhere

```
public static function getColorBasedOnEvent($event){
    switch(strtoupper($event)){
        case "START":
            return '#4f5705';
        case "STOP":
            return '#f43f1a';
        default:
            return '#8acae7'
     }
}
```

and then on the view

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 210px;">
        <table class="table" id="">
                <tr>
                    <th>Program Time</th>
                    <th>Event</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Actual_time</th>
                    <th>Display_Message</th>
                </tr>
            <tbody >
            @foreach($welcome as $key => $data)
                <tr>    
                <td>{{$data->program_time}}</td>
                <td style="background-color:{{controllername::getColorBasedOnEvent($data->event)}}">{{$data->event}}</td>
                <td>{{$data->message}}</td> 
                <td>{{$data->actual_time}}</td>               
                <td>{{$data->display_message}}</td>                  
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
    <div>
```

ps: for information don't call Model::all()->where, because it will get all the record from the database first and then filter it.

use Model::where() instead

Comment: Hi. I just got it working . It works perfectly. Thank you too. Only small thing I added was the namespace of my controller before the 'controllername' == 'App\Http\Controllers\Mycontroller:: ... Thanks Again!